# Hyper-v and Visual Studio community

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, emulation, virtualization, hyper-v

I have Windows 10 Pro x64 installed on my machine with Visual Studio community as well, however I need Windows Phone emulators for Xamarin testing. Visual Studio keeps telling me:

> This computer does not support Windows Phone emulator, which requires the 64-bit edition of Windows 8.1 Pro and a computer that supports Hyper-V.

Spec of my PC:

- AMD Phenom II X4 810 Processor (Supports SLAT)
- 8GB of RAM
- Gigabyte M720-US3 Motherboard
- Award modular BIOS v6.00PG

So I tried to enable Hyper-v for my computer by enabling virtualization in BIOS. Then I went to the Control panel and tried to enable Hyper-v there, but it seems like I can't. The tooltip says I cannot install hyper-v and that the firmware disables support for virtualization.

[Hyper-v grayed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G6Wmx.png)

I also let a little AMD utility check for support for hyper-v and this is the result:

[I should enable AMD-v however I didn't find any option like that in my BIOS. Only thing called simply "virtualization" I enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwAxP.png)

I don't know what else I could do for it. Any idea? Thank you very much!

Comment: Time to contact the computer vendor.